# NSIS. Create a fill in form to write the inserted data into a txt file

Tags: installation, nsis

Just started using NSIS for my first installer. Found everything that i need apart from one thing only. I found how to write and create a txt file but couldn't find any info whether it is possible or not to allow the user to do some input (open a form in the installer) and then write the inserted data into a txt file.

Right now i'm able to write an input from an nsDialog, this is the code:

```
nsDialogs::Create 1018
Pop $Dialog

${NSD_CreateText} 10% 20u 80% 12u "Insert the API KEY"

Pop $Text
nsDialogs::Show


${NSD_GetText} $Text $0
MessageBox MB_OK "You typed:$\n$\n$0"

FileOpen $0 "$DESKTOP\Hello_world.txt" w
FileWrite $0 $Text
FileClose $0
```

However, the problem is that the data that is being written in the Hello_world.txt are some random digits, right now i'm not really understanding what are these numbers, shouldn't $Text be a String?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam

Comment: @idleberg i'v tried to edit my question to be more precise, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The dialog (and its child controls) only exists between `nsDialogs::Create` and `nsDialogs::Show`. You get random information because you are trying to read from something that no longer exists. Also, in your example `$Text` is the edit control handle (HWND), not the text, your text would be in `$0` in your case.

> To finalize and display the dialog you must call `nsDialogs::Show`. This function will not return until the user clicks Next, Back or Cancel.

You should read user input in the leave callback of a page:

```
Page Custom MyPageCreate MyPageLeave
Page Directory
Page InstFiles

Var MyTextControlHandle

Function MyPageCreate
nsDialogs::Create 1018
Pop $0

${NSD_CreateText} 10% 20u 80% 12u "Insert the API KEY"
Pop $MyTextControlHandle

nsDialogs::Show
; $MyTextControlHandle is no longer valid here
FunctionEnd

Function MyPageLeave
${NSD_GetText} $MyTextControlHandle $0 ; Get text from $MyTextControlHandle and store in $0
MessageBox MB_OK "You typed:$\n$\n$0"
; Save $0 somewhere if desired
FunctionEnd
```